# AUTO-Scynhronize a table based on view - ORACLE DATABASES

Tags: oracle

I want to ask you if there is a solution to auto-synchronize  a table ,e.g., every one minute based on view created in oracle.
This view is using data from another table. I've created a trigger but I noticed a big slowness in database whenever a user update a column or insert a row.
Furthermore, I've tested to create a job schedule on the specified table (Which I wanted to be synchronized with the view), however we don't have the privilege to do this.
Is there any other way to keep data updated between the table and the view ?
PS : I'm using toad for oracle V 12.9.0.71

Comment: It sounds like you want a materialized view https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm  You'd need to look at the query used to create the view and the restrictions on materialized views, to figure out whether a materialized view is possible and, if so, what materialized view logs you would need.

Comment: Actually, I've never worked with a materialized view. I've tested to change the view into a materialized one but the data has not been updated when I modified a value in the table used on this view.

Comment: If you want to update your question to include a reproducible test case, that would probably be a good question that you'll get some answers on.  Otherwise, it's impossible to guess at how you've defined the materialized view and materialized view logs and why it isn't refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

A materialized view in Oracle is a database object that contains the results of a query. They are local copies of data located remotely, or are used to create summary tables based on aggregations of a table's data. Materialized views, which store data based on remote tables, are also known as snapshots.

Example:

```
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_emp_pk
    REFRESH FAST START WITH SYSDATE 
    NEXT  SYSDATE + 1/48
    WITH PRIMARY KEY 
    AS SELECT * FROM emp@remote_db;
```

You can use cronjob or dbms_jobs to schedule a snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
First, I created a MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG on the table used in the query as bellow : 
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON <tab1> WITH PRIMARY KEY, ROWID including new values; 
Then, I created the materialized view with the following parameters :
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW <My_View>
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
...
However, this creation ends with an error : ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view

Comment: the following is example

Comment: user TESTUSER
TAMPONI

Comment: GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO TAMPONI;

Comment: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW emp_mv
  2  REFRESH FORCE
  3  ON DEMAND
  4  AS
  5  SELECT * FROM testuser.emp
  6  /
Materialized view created.

Comment: if you select * from emp_mv, you will get snapshot for emp.

Comment: if you table is small or you  are not concern performance, you can drop material view each time.

Comment: exec dbms_mview.refresh('EMP_MV',atomic_refresh=>TRUE);

Comment: the above comment is executed by material view owner

Comment: I use 3 materialized views. One of them combines two views using UNION. 
Using REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND doesn't make the view synchronized e.g. when I updated a value in the table used in the main view
However, an error has been encountered "ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view"  while trying to use ON COMMIT instead of ON DEMAND.